# There is a bug with the "Download Libraries for Neural Network" on VQGAN+CLIP.ipynb. How can I fix it?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHupX.jpg)

How can I fix it (I don't understand the Python language)?

I need to know what to do to fix it.

Comment: Please post the relevant code and the FULL error message (click on the 2 frames button to expand it before copy pasting). Use the `{}` button in the editor to format the code